# Update query using joins

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
UPDATE project_phases p2 
SET 
  p2.ClartiyID = @ClarityID,
  p2.Start_date = @start_date,
  p2.End_date = @End_date,
  p2.Planned_efforts = @Planned_efforts 
FROM 
  WSR.dbo.project_phases p2 
  INNER JOIN WSR.dbo.tb_Project p1 ON p1.ProjectID=p2.ProjectID 
WHERE 
  ProjectID = @ProjectID
```

but still the error diplays like object name not found even though that table found

Comment: If anyone manages to decipher this "question", I will give them a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your whole query, why are you linking to tb_Project?  It seems like this is only to filter on ProjectID, but this column is in Project_Phases so can't you foget the INNER JOIN and just use:

```
UPDATE project_phases 
SET 
  ClartiyID = @ClarityID,
  Start_date = @start_date,
  End_date = @End_date,
  Planned_efforts = @Planned_efforts 
WHERE 
  ProjectID = @ProjectID
```